# Pass app object from Parent to Node child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

I am working on creating a child process. As a part of that I need to pass the app object from parent to child process.

parent.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  // app object is available here. Need to pass this to child
  const path = require("path");
  const cp = require('child_process');
  let child = cp.fork(__dirname + '../../worker/worker.js');
  child.on('message', (app) => {
        console.log('Message from child', app);
  });

  child.send({ 'app': app });
};
```

worker.js

```
process.on('message', (app) => {
    console.log('Message from parent:', app);
});
```

Output I am getting now is : Message from parent: {}

Can you tell me spawn or fork I have to use. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: did you solve this. or did you use other method if yes then which?